Origin of the phrase "Ich glaub mein Schwein pfeift"
The phrase,

Ich glaub' mein Schwein pfeift

literary translates to “I think my pig is whistling". Idiomatically it is a way to convey shock and astonishment when confronted with an unbelievable or completely unexpected situation. Intuitively, it does make sense that a pig whistling would be something unexpected. Regardless, I was keen on knowing on how this phrase originated and whether you use it to convey astonishment towards an unexpected disappointing situation, or to an ironic/hysterical situation? (Whether it is used in a negative or a positive situation)

The phrase "Ich glaub mein Schwein pfeift" is a humorous and idiomatic German expression that translates to "I think my pig is whistling" in English. It is used to convey surprise, disbelief, or astonishment, similar to the English phrases "I can't believe it" or "You've got to be kidding me."

I wonder if you tried to find that out yourself because this link is the first one to come up when searching for:

mein schwein pfeift herkunft

in DuckDuckGo.
Anyway, according to this site the origin is unclear and a common misconception (that it was invented in the seventies by the "Spontis", unorganised leftists) is provably wrong because the phrase was already widely in use in the fourties.
Their own theory is that it was invented in Berlin in the twenties and "Schwein" means a round pot to boil water, which looks similar to a piggy bank. These pots gave a whistling tone when the water was boiling and to extricate oneself from an unwelcome conversation one would say "ich glaube, mein Schwein pfeift" to go to the kitchen. This usage would then change to express bewilderment.
Notice that all this is without any source and hence the explanation is as good as any other but it is (almost word-by-word) repeated here so probably one copied from the other.
The same story is told here but in different words. They also compare that to the British idiom it's like to teach the pigs to play the flute.
Another website also tells the same story but with less detail and also without giving any source.
To the contrary, Redensarten-Index says it is from the sixties, also without giving any source or reason, so at least one of these two groups must be wrong.
